# Background color of top navbar not the text

Tags: html, css

I want to change the background color of top navbar, How I can fill the top nav bar full width color not only text backgground color ? 
here is the code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-collapse">
            <div class="topnavbar">
                Brand Here
            </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-collapse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
              </div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>

CSS 

.topnavbar {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color: rgb(60, 165, 29);

}
```

[I am talking about Green part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkZBU.png)

Comment: What do you imagine `background-color: rgb(60, 165, 29);` does? Has it not occured to you to change that?

Answer (score 0):

To change the full width of the div you need to set the width on html and body to 100%. You also need to set the margins to 0. Lastly, set the navbar class to width:100% as well.

Basically, setting width to 100% means a container takes up the full width of the parent. So you have to set all the parents of the `.topnavbar` to 100% width.

```
.topnavbar {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color: rgb(60, 165, 29);
    width:100%;
}

html,body{
 width:100%; 
 margin-left:0;
 margin-right:0;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/8tc3z6kq/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `.topnavbar` element has `margin` that is not affected by `background-color`. You can use `padding` instead, but you will still have white 15px `padding` on sides due to `.navbar-collapse` element. You can mitigate it by putting negative margin on `.topnavbar`, like so:

```
.topnavbar {
    margin: 0 -15px;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 30px;
    background-color: rgb(60, 165, 29);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Too get nav full width background (lets call it that) I only left this in your CSS.

```
body,html{
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.topnavbar {
background-color: rgb(60, 165, 29);
padding: 10px;
```

}

Just remove margins and should be fine. And for different background-color just use different rgba or hex codes.I have added a bit of padding to look a wee nicer.

[See What You Get Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvyYH.png)

Hope this helps .
Kind Regards